# URL encoding for + sign not registering in https://ics.agical.io calendar invite URL on Google Calendar

Tags: url, google-calendar-api, urlencode

Currently using this structure for a google calendar invite URL:

https://ics.agical.io/?subject=.....&location=......&dtstart=.......&dtend=.....&description=.......&format=gcal

%2B the url encoding for + is not appearing in my google event. Here's an example

https://ics.agical.io/?subject=This%20is%20a%20test%21%2B&organizer=This%20is%20a%20test%21%2B%40gmail.com&location=https://stackoverflow.com/&dtstart=2023-10-24T23:00:00.000Z&dtend=2023-10-25T02:00:00.000Z&description=This%20is%20a%20test%21%2B&reminder=15&attach=https://stackoverflow.com/&format=gcal

Does anyone know how to resolve this to ensure the + appears in the event metadata fields?

I attempted masking the URL in a vanity URL which failed but not sure what else to try. To make it an apple calendar event, just need to remove /&format=gcal from the end. Apple calendar invites show the + just fine.